# extract string 1.jpg from string ;1.jpg:2.jpg:3.jpg

Tags: c#, string, replace, extract

I have a string

```
;1234.jpg;1356.jpg;7890.jpg
```

I want to have 1234.jpg and 1356.jpg and 7890.jpg , each in different string.

Any Idea !
and yes I am using VS 2010 with C#, i just need some idea behind it...let's do

```
   string allimage = ";1234.jpg;1356.jpg;7890.jpg";
```

I want to have

```
string a;    // here i want 1234.jpg
string b;    //  here i want 1356.jpg
string c;    // here i want 7890.jpg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String.Split(Char[], StringSplitOptions)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx) method like;

```
string str = ";1234.jpg;1356.jpg;7890.jpg";
string[] array = str.Split(new char[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string a = array[0];
string b = array[1];
string c = array[2];

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Output will be;

```
1234.jpg
1356.jpg
7890.jpg
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/eOdql0).

Comment: how can i vote up ? i'm not having Reputation more than 15 :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string allimage = dt.rows[0]["listing_media"].tostring();
var images = allimage.Split(new char[]{';'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string a = images[0];
string b = images[1];
string c = images[2];
```

It will split your string to list of strings and remove empty first entry.

Comment: Using `';'` instead of `";"` is better because of the right overload which is  [`Split(Char[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the C# String-Split:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b873y76a(v=vs.85).aspx

And use RemoveEmptyEntries, so you can't get any empty entries ;)

```
    string[] cSplitted = ";1234.jpg;1356.jpg;7890.jpg".Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach(string cString in cSplitted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cString);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```